# IF SET unexpectend error Batch file

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement, cmd, set

I have got a problem with my batch file!

I want to get echo like :

*1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4*
Or: *4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1*

So when I reach **4** by pressing *d* the next press should be switch the variable to **1**

 And when I reach **1** by pressing *a* the next press should be switch the variable to **4**

I dont get the echo at last, but I get syntax error. Please check the mistakes!
Here is the sample code:

```
@echo off 
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set direction =1

:top
choice /c ad /n /m Move:
if errorlevel 1 (
set /a "direction -=1")

if errorlevel 2 (
set /a "direction +=2")

if %direction% == "4"(
set direction=1)

if %direction% == "1"(
set direction=4 )

echo !direction!
goto top
```

Many thanks for help !

Comment: So... what's the problem?

Comment: Among the things I think are causing you issues:  your comparisons are not correct, i.e. even if `direction` holds a value of 4, `4` does not equal `"4"`.  I'd also question your spacing where you set the variables.

Comment: I checked it and the problem is the same.

Comment: What's the problem?!!

Comment: it say command syntax error

Answer (score 2):

As Marc correctly stated, your problem is this command:

```
set direction =1
```

It sets a variable named "`direction`" to 1 (note the space!)

So the following statement:

```
if %direction% == "1"
```

is (correctly) expanded to:

```
   if  == "1"
```

(because `%direction%` does not exist; your variable is `%direction %`)
you can (and should) avoid the syntax error by putting BOTH sides into parantheses:
    if "%direction%" == "1" 
this will expand to

```
if "" == "1"
```

not, what you want, but the syntax is ok now.
To set the variable correctly, use the `set`command without spaces:

set direction=1

or even better (not needed in this case, but sometimes it helps much):

set "direction=1"

This eliminates the possibilty for a trailing space (`1`)

These two steps should solve your problem.

EDIT: there are some logical problems in your code:

- in one direction you add one, in the other direction you subtract two (shold be one according to your example)
- you check for "4" as overrun. You should check for "5", as 4 is ok (according to your example): if it's 5, set it to 1
- you check for "1" as underrun. You should check for "0". If it's 0, set it to 4

Comment: Oh, I forgot: When I add one and subtract one, there was no difference in numbers at addition.       I mean: _1_ --> press _d_ --> _1_. So I added two.

Comment: @recon `if /?`: `if errorlevel 1` checks, if errorlevel is 1 **or higher**. As 2 indeed **is** higher than 1, both IFs are correct, if errorlevel is 2. To be sure, use `if %errorlevel%==1` instead. That does no numerical but string comparison.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, you are the one normal person here :) Thanks

Comment: Well, I'm working on it ;-) But really: if you need help, you'll get help. If you need more help, you'll get more help. If you ask for code, you will get nothing. That's how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a direction=1

:top
choice /c ad /n /m Move:
if errorlevel 1 set /a direction -=1

if errorlevel 2 set /a direction +=2

if %direction%==4 set /a direction=1

if "%direction%"=="1" set /a direction=4

echo !direction!
goto top
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's some partially-corrected code to set you in the right direction.

First issue, as already noted is that spaces on **EITHER** side of a string-assignment are included literally, hence the <kbd>Space</kbd> would be included in variable name. The syntax `set "var=value"` is used to ensure that trailing spaces on the line are **NOT** included in the value assigned **OR** a defined number of spaces assigned, so `set "var=value   "` would include 3 spaces at the end of value (your editor may try to delete them - this is insurance)

the `set /a` syntax is for a NUMERIC assign and is only interested in numeric values, hence it doesn't care about spaces included in the assignment. HOWEVER - batch ALWAYS works on STRINGS, the `set /a` facility is mere convenience; the value stored is a string.

Next problem is `if errorlevel n` - it's true when `errorlevel` is equal to `n` **OR GREATER THAN** `n`. Hence, when `errorlevel` is 2 for an input of `d` BOTH of yout `if errorlevel` statements will be true. This probably isn't what you want.

Clasically, you would deal with this by interpreting in reverse-value order and `GOTO` over the remaining `if errorlevel`s.

The variable `%errorlevel%` is set automatically to contain the current `errorlevel`.

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==2 ...
```

may solve your problem.

Next is the difference between STRING and NUMERIC comparisons. `set /a var=17` would set `var` to a value of `17`. `17` and "17"`are entirely different strings, so if`var`is known numeric=17,`if %var% gtr 9`would be true because`17`is greater than`9`, but`if "%var%" gtr "9"`would be FALSE because`1`is LESS than`9`

Finally, a syntax note - If you use a code block (ie a parenthesised [series of] statement[s]) then

1. There must be a separator before the opening parenthesis of the `IF` true-condition target
2. That opening parenthesis must be on the same physical line as the `if`
3. Where an 'else' clause is used, the ending parenthesis of the "true" block, a separator and the `else` keyword must be on the same physical line
4. Where an 'else' block is used, the `else` keyword, a separator and the opening parenthesis of the "else" block must be on the same physical line

ie

```
if condition (
 something
) else (
 someotherthing
)
```